# Difference between "приду" and "прийду"

Tags: грамматика, глаголы

What is the difference between **приду** and **прийду**?
Both mean: I will come?(on foot)

Also **я приеду** and **я прийеду** mean: I will come?(by vehicle)
Again what is the difference of them?

Comment: https://mel.fm/gramotnost/7698251-will_come

Comment: where exactly you've encountered "прийеду" form?

Comment: @shabunc My Russian teacher wrote for me !

Comment: @sergey-slepov Thank you so much for the link

Comment: @WorldLover your Russian teacher did a very strange thing to be honest

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Прийду** is an outdated norm, the verb **идти** and its derivatives being, probably, the most miraculous of the Russian verb family representatives.

E.g., there were three ways you could write **прийти**, which were **придти, притти и прийти**.

Leave alone the fact that the verb идти is an infinitive ending in **ти** instead of **ть**, like all the other infinitives.

It seems to be just logical, that the infinitive **прийти** should make up the personal forms *я прийду, ты прийдёшь*, etc., and it was actually a norm. And it sounds like that. But nowadays the **й** has remained only in the verbs not containing и like **подойти, отойти,** **уйти**: **я уйду, ты уйдёшь**.

The ий has been assimilated and reduced to и. Nowadays it's just one и there. **Приду is the norm**.

And **прийеду** is not more than **a mockery based on the analogy with the verb прийду**. )))))

Comment: "идти is an infinitive ending in ти instead of ть, like all the other infinitives" There are at least 256 other such verbs: http://gramdict.ru/search/%2A%D1%82%D0%B8?symbol=%D1%81%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%B2,%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%B2,%D1%81%D0%B2

Answer (score 4):

"Прийду" and "прийеду" are ungrammatical. While "прийду" is a common mistake, "прийеду" is simply totally off.

Comment: thank you for your answer